# Как создать консольное приложение под консольное приложение, а не под библиотеку?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь написать простенькую программу, но у меня вместо кнопки "пуск" есть только кнопка "присоединить". Я даже в списке вариантов программ при создании заметил, что можно создать консольное, а можно создать под библиотеку, нажал, и всё равно то же самое. Visual Studio 2019

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: При нажатии кнопки "присоединить"]
[image: Кстати, если закрыть приложение и запустить его ещё раз, то вообще весь код пропадает]

Comment: Не понял практически всё. Давайте проблему по шагам и со скриншотами. Словами у вас объяснить не получилось.

Comment: что будет если нажать присоединить?

Comment: Если закрыть и запустить приложение, то код пропадает

Comment: По "присоединить" предпоследняя картинка

Comment: Выглядит как пустое решение, в котором нет ни одного проекта, возможно с шаблонами для студии какая-то проблема. Галочку "поместить проект и решение в одном месте" пробовали не ставить при создании проекта? Ее вообще не рекомендуется ставить.

Comment: Галочку убрал - то же самое

Comment: Видите надопись "проектов: 0", это и есть источник проблемы. В это решение нужно добавить проект. Правой кнопкой по решению, "Добавить новый проект". Почему вы попали в такую ситуацию, я не знаю, это не нормально. Возможно полная переустановка студии с сайта Microsoft поможет исправить проблему с шаблонами. Вы же с официального сайта устанавливали? И вообще можно 2022 студию поставить.

Comment: Не с официального сайта ставил, потому что в 2021 году. А 2022 какая-то тормознутая, наверно, из-за того что у меня Windows 7. Получается, что единственный выход-это покупка нового компьютера)

Answer (score 1):

Для Visual Studio 2019 набор тех типов проектов, которые можно создавать, определяется при установке, вот в таком примерно окне - см. ниже.

Когда VS уже установлена - можно удалять-добавлять компонеты, зайдя в `Visual Studio Installer`. Он есть в списке установденных программ, рядом с Visual Studio.

Просто добавьте там нужные типы проектов, и всё заработает.

[image: сетап]

Но, лично от себя, я бы посоветовал *никогда* не пользоваться русифицированными версиями программ при разработке. Это приводит к **аду** в области наименований.

Comment: То, что Вы обвели, у меня установлено(галочка стоит)

Comment: Ну, тогда по совету aepot - снимите Ваши действия, сделав скринкаст, или хотя бы нащёлкайте картинок с экрана!

Comment: Картинки вставил в вопрос